# Traefik basicauth for path

Tags: traefik

I want basicauth to apply just to /admin path:

```
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.app.rule=Host(`host.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.app_auth.basicauth.usersfile=/etc/traefik/basicauth"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app_admin.rule=Host(`host.com`) && Path(`/admin`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app_admin.middlewares=app_auth"
      ...
```

This is configuration is not working. What am I missing?

Comment: You using traefik v2 docker container, right?

Comment: Also, can you pls tell me, if its not working at all or is it requiring auth on both `host.com` and `host.com/admin`.

Comment: yes I am using Docker provider. If I apply middleware to `app` route it is working.

Comment: I can see that you have not defined/shared the entrypoints and other stuff. Would you mind sharing a bit more of the labels/configs? So that I can have a better idea of your setup.

Comment: Also, what response do you get when you visit `host.com/admin` with this config.

Comment: I have just one entrypoint do I need explicitly define? When I visit /admin it opens as not protected.

Comment: Can you try using `PathPrefix` instead of `Path` and see if that solves your problem?

Comment: `PathPrefix` makes no difference. Did you succeed setting authentication to path? I am wondering if traefik is capable of doing this?

Comment: After seeing your question, I have been tinkering with `Path` and `PathPrefix` by changing a traefik configuration I already had setup few days ago for automatic wildcard certificates and stuff...  
And It does work and ask for authentication for the paths specified, I am not sure what is happening in your case...
`Path` needs an exact match while `PathPrefix` will also accept anything after the the path provided.